# Ionic - Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git via registry

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I just created a new app with the next command:

```
ionic start myapp
```

Everything works fine but when I try to deploy to Android (My Android studio environment is properly installed and configured), I get the next error:

> Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-statusbar@https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git
>           via registry.

I try to deploy with:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Just run this command:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-statusbar
```

Now I can deploy my app but I don't know why that plugin is not installed automatically.

Comment: Add this plugin. It added successfully. But it show error while using firebase  : `import firebase from 'firebase';
import {Firebase} from '@ionic-native/firebase'; `     Cannot find module 'firebase', Cannot find module '@ionic-native/firebase'.

Comment: @UnnatiPatadia try with import { Firebase } from '@ionic-native/firebase/ngx';

Answer (score 5):

This work for me, If the other solutions did,t work

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar.git`